# Upload HTML5 canvas image to Facebook through javascript api

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook-graph-api, canvas

Presently, I am able to upload an image to Facebook through it's javascript api but I need to save the image on my server which is taking time. 
I want to upload the canvas image directly to Facebook without saving it on server and it should work with IE9 too, is there any tutorial or documentation to achieve this?